# In Angular2 how do you update a Form Control WIHTOUT using ngModel or setter/getter?

Tags: angular

so I have this form and I don't want to use ngModel or setter / getter per control. Instead I used observables on the entire form with debounce to get latest form data... which is great to 'GET'... but now I need to handle the populating of form fields manually... (which I grab from a Redux store) and since control.value is read only that wont work.

what's the proper way of updating a form control (AbstractControl) without using ngModel?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `updateValue` method of the `Control` class to do that:

```
control.updateValue(newValue);
```

Comment: TX, I was typing it as AbstractControl instead of  Control so didn't get the proper intelisence... the wonders and pitfalls of typescript :) TX!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the control just

```
control.updateValue(newValue);
```

Comment: TX, I was typing it as AbstractControl instead of  Control so didn't get the proper intelisence... the wonders and pitfalls of typescript :) TX!!!